# How to move an image depending on mouse location using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I would like an image to move to the left if the mouse is to the left of the screen and to the right if the mouse to the right of the screen, using javascript, here is the code I have so far:

```
    var dirx = 0;  
    var spdx = 35; 
    var imgLeftInt; 
    var imgTopInt; 
    var imgHeight; 
    var imgWidth; 
    var divWidth; 
    var divHeight; 
    var t;
    var tempX;
    var tempY;
```

So I'm pretty sure I'm not missing any variables...

```
    function animBall(on) {               
        imgLeftInt = parseInt(document.images['logo'].style.left); 
        imgTopInt = parseInt(document.images['logo'].style.top); 
        imgHeight =  parseInt(document.images['logo'].height); 
        imgWidth =  parseInt(document.images['logo'].width); 
        divWidth = parseInt(document.images['container'].width);        
        if (tempX > 779){
            dirx = 1;
        } 
        else if(tempX < 767){
            dirx = 2;
        }
        else {
            spdx = 0;
        }
```

So if tempX, which should be the x coordinate of the mouse location, is bigger than 779, which is the halfway point of the div tag, the image should go right. If it's less than that, it should go left, and otherwise, the speed should be zero, as in it should stay still.

```
        if(dirx == 1){                            
            goRight(); 
        } else if(dirx == 2) {                                      
            goLeft(); 
        }        
    }
    function getMouseXY(e) {
        tempX = e.clientX;
        tempY = e.clientY;
        }
```

I found hundreds of different ways to get the mouse location, but this was off W3C so I assume it works.

```
    function goRight() { 
        document.images['logo'].style.left = imgLeftInt+spdx +"px"; 
        if (imgLeftInt >  (divWidth-imgWidth)){ 
            dirx = 2; 
            spdx= 20; 
        } 
    } 

    function goLeft() { 
        document.images['logo'].style.left = (imgLeftInt-spdx) +"px"; 
        if (imgLeftInt <  5){ 
            dirx = 1; 
            spdx= 20; 
        } 
    } 

    </script>
```

So that's my whole script.

```
    <div id="container" onmousemove="getMouseXY(event);" width="1546" height="423">
        <a href="javascript:var t=setInterval('animBall()', 80)">Start Animation</a> <a href="javascript:clearInterval(t);">Stop Animation</a> <br /> 
        <img src="http://qabila.tv/images/logo_old.png" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:20px;" id="logo" /> 
    </div>
```

I left the dependency on the mouse location to the very end so the animation script works fine (or at least worked, unless I broke something trying to get it to read the mouse location).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong??

If it's any help, I've hosted the code [here.](http://qabila.tv/teamlab/test3.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well that needed a whole load of work, anyway, I have done some of it for you and you can now see things partially working, but you will need to play with it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/GdmjW/). Perhaps you can now open some specific questions regarding getting this to work.

```
<div id="container" width="1546" height="423"> <a id="start" href="#">Start Animation</a>  <a id="stop" href="#">Stop Animation</a> 
    <br />
    <img src="http://qabila.tv/images/logo_old.png" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:20px;" id="logo" />
</div>

/*jslint sub: true, maxerr: 50, indent: 4, browser: true */
/*global */

(function () {
    "use strict";

    var start = document.getElementById("start"),
        stop = document.getElementById("stop"),
        container = document.getElementById("container"),
        logo = document.getElementById("logo"),
        dirx = 0,
        spdx = 35,
        imgLeftInt,
        imgTopInt,
        imgHeight,
        imgWidth,
        divWidth,
        divHeight,
        t,
        tempX,
        tempY;

    function getMouseXY(e) {
        tempX = e.clientX;
        tempY = e.clientY;
    }

    function goRight() {
        logo.style.left = imgLeftInt + spdx + "px";
        if (imgLeftInt > (divWidth - imgWidth)) {
            dirx = 2;
            spdx = 20;
        }
    }

    function goLeft() {
        logo.style.left = (imgLeftInt - spdx) + "px";
        if (imgLeftInt < 5) {
            dirx = 1;
            spdx = 20;
        }
    }

    // attribute on unused
    function animBall(on) {
        imgLeftInt = parseInt(logo.style.left, 10);
        imgTopInt = parseInt(logo.style.top, 10);
        imgHeight = parseInt(logo.height, 10);
        imgWidth = parseInt(logo.width, 10);
        divWidth = parseInt(container.width, 10);

        if (tempX > 779) {
            dirx = 1;
        } else if (tempX < 767) {
            dirx = 2;
        } else {
            spdx = 0;
        }

        if (dirx === 1) {
            goRight();
        } else if (dirx === 2) {
            goLeft();
        }
    }

    function startAnim() {
        t = setInterval(animBall, 80);
    }

    start.addEventListener("click", startAnim, false);

    function stopAnim() {
        clearInterval(t);
    }

    stop.addEventListener("click", stopAnim, false);

    container.addEventListener("mousemove", getMouseXY, false);
}());
```

Comment: I've hosted your code [here](http://qabila.tv/teamlab/test4.html), not sure what I'm doing wrong but there doesn't seem to be any movement.

Answer (score 0):

I went to your link and tried debugging your code.  I get an error on line 21 because your document has no "container" image ("container" is a div).

At the start of your question, you said you wanted to know mouse position relative to center of "screen". For that, you'd probably want to use window.innerWidth instead of the width attribute that you set on your div.

Comment: totally agreed on that - it will just work as the mouse is hovering over the div.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you usee the html5 canvas and [gee.js](http://georgealways.github.io/gee/)

Here's the js fiddle result (it may take a while to load, but that's fault of jsfiddle, the script will load much faster once on your website): http://jsfiddle.net/wLCeE/7/embedded/result/

and here's the much simpler code to make it work:

```
var g = new GEE({
    width: 500,
    height: 423,
    container: document.getElementById('canvas')
});

var img = new Image(); // Create new img element
img.onload = function () {
    demo(g)
};
img.src = 'http://qabila.tv/images/logo_old.png'; // Set source path

function demo(g) {

    var style = "left"

    g.draw = function () {

        if (g.mouseX > g.width / 2 && style == "left") styleRight()
        else if (g.mouseX < g.width / 2 && style == "right") styleLeft()

    }

    function styleLeft() {
        style = "left"
        g.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, g.width, g.height)
        g.ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)

    }

    function styleRight() {
        style = "right"
        g.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, g.width, g.height)
        g.ctx.drawImage(img, g.width - img.width, 0)

    }



}
```